# tensorfow tf.expand_dims Error

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm beginner in tensorflow and i use **tf.expand_dims** and i get error which i can't understand the reason , so what am i missing?

This is the code

```
ML_OUTPUT = None
input_for_classification = None
def ConstructML( input_tensor, layers_count, node_for_each_layer):
    global   ML_OUTPUT 
    global input_for_classification 
    FeatureVector = np.array(input_tensor)
    FeatureVector = FeatureVector.flatten()
    print(FeatureVector.shape)                           
    ML_ModelINT(FeatureVector, layers_count, node_for_each_layer)

def ML_ModelINT(FeatureVector, layers_count, node_for_each_layer):
        hidden_layer = []
        Alloutputs = []
        hidden_layer.append({'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([FeatureVector.shape[0], node_for_each_layer[0]])),'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_for_each_layer[0]]))})
        for i in range(1, layers_count):
            hidden_layer.append({'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_for_each_layer[i - 1], node_for_each_layer[i]])),'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([node_for_each_layer[i]]))})
        FeatureVector = tf.expand_dims(FeatureVector,0)
        layers_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(FeatureVector, hidden_layer[0]['weights']), hidden_layer[0]['biases'])
        layers_output = tf.nn.relu(layers_output)
        Alloutputs.append(layers_output)
        for j in range(1, layers_count):
            layers_output = tf.add(tf.matmul(layers_output, hidden_layer[j]['weights']), hidden_layer[j]['biases'])
            layers_output = tf.nn.relu(layers_output)
            Alloutputs.append(layers_output)
        ML_OUTPUT = layers_output  
        input_for_classification = Alloutputs[1]             
        return ML_OUTPUT

 ML_Net = ConstructML(input,3,[1024,512,256])
```

And it give me error in this line

```
    FeatureVector = tf.expand_dims(FeatureVector,0)
```

The error is  **Expected binary or unicode string, got tf.Tensor 'Relu_11:0' shape=(?, 7, 7, 512) dtype=float32**

**Note** The input is output tensor of another network and it is works well

Comment: something is strange with your types, I think ... in function ConstructML, FeatureVector is a numpy array. Then you pass it to ModelINT, and run a tf tensor operation on it without having it converted ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, the **numpy** part was the error because when **predection** function is firstly called it has no feed yet for input_imgs and numpy code will not be excuted correctly, and i replaced it with tensorflow ops and it is worked now.